# Accessing C# function in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, d3.js, awesomium

I think there is something that I don't understand as I proceed forward in my project of importing D3 visuals into Spotfire.

I currently have implemented a D3 visualization into Spotfire by using Awesomium's embedded browser and these lines:

```
        string myString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\leear\Desktop\SDK\SDK\Examples\Extensions\D3Visualizations\Gauge.html");
        webView.LoadHTML(myString);
```

The HTML of Gauge.html contains javascript code that runs all the necessary things to create the visualization.

However, I want to be able to access/run C# functions and variables inside the Gauge.html file. I am envisioning something like this:

```
for (var value in <%=Spotfire.getCurrentColumn()%>) {gauge.redraw(value)}
```

My project is currently structured just for the C# code to read and write all the HTML from a file into Awesomium's embedded browser.

How would I do this? Where does aspx.NET fit into this, if at all?

Thanks

Comment: Does it need to be a Winform application? ASP.NET is server-side technology that seves HTML pages to user browser and yes it can help, but if you develop a browser app

Answer (score 1):

You can't; javascript is client-side, and ASP.NET is server side.  ASP.NET basically generates HTML and javascript, and once that rendering is done the page is processed the client-side takes over, which it knows nothing of ASP.NET.  It's perfectly fine for ASP.NET to spit out JS becuase it's RENDERING it, but the client-side PROCESSING of JS, which is where you are trying to call a server-side method knows nothing of ASP.NET.  You'd have to move the logic to the client, or have the client talk to the server using javascript.

I can't advise further as I don't know what that method does.

Comment: That makes sense.
I may end up editing the javascript code in C# every single time the "run" button is pressed, and then reload the webview's HTML from scratch, so that D3 is always running a predefined script, although it is changed every single time a change happens in Spotfire.

Comment: Yes, or there are excellent tools for managing HTML on the client, so you aren't constantly round-tripping to the server.

Answer (score 0):

"You can't; javascript is client-side, and ASP.NET is server side. ASP.NET basically generates HTML and javascript"....

This is absolutely correct. Client and server are two different worlds...
You have a couple of options if you need to get code-reuse.
Look into a C# to javascript compiler..and make sure your C# functions don't depend on anything related to the server or its runtime.

Otherwise, consider exposing your server functionality as a web service that takes input of some form and returns output as JSON for use on the client side.